# How to display checkbox instead of bool variable in yii2 gridview?

Tags: gridview, checkbox, yii2

I want to show some rows in yii2 gridview. one of column's type is BIT(`correspondingAuthorFlag`) in mysql table.
now I want to display checkbox(checked for 1, unchecked for 0) instead of thier values. for this reason I wrote follow codes:

```
  $widget = Yii::createObject([
                'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
                'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
                'columns' => [
                    'PersonName',
                    'PersonType',
                    'order',
                    [
                     'value' => 'correspondingAuthorFlag',
                     'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                    ],
                ],

            ]
        );
```

but it throws an error. how can I do it?

Comment: show the error message

Comment: What do you want to do with these checkboxes? Should they be editable? Are you want to use these values for form submitting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `checkboxOptions` :

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
    'columns' => [
        'PersonName',
        'PersonType',
        'order',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'checkboxOptions' => function($model) {
                return ['checked' => $model->correspondingAuthorFlag == 1 ? true : false];
            }
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: why not  return ['checked' => $model->correspondingAuthorFlag == 1];

Comment: @kusanagi It works fine that way, I added the full statement for more readability

Answer (score 0):

I've found it and done by these codes:

```
     $widget = Yii::createObject([
                'class' => 'yii\grid\GridView',
                'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
                'columns' => [
                    'PersonName',
                    'PersonType',
                    'order',

                    ['attribute' => 'correspondingAuthorFlag',
                        'value' => function ($data) {
                            if ($data['correspondingAuthorFlag'] == '1') {
                              return Html::checkbox('correspondingAuthorFlag',1,['disabled' => true]);
                            } else {
                                return Html::checkbox('correspondingAuthorFlag',0,['disabled' => true]);

                            }

                        }
                        , 'format' => 'raw'
                    ]

                ],

            ]
        );
```

using this way, we can add any html control to gridview. :)